# Draw Line Chart Using Chart.js

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I want to draw line chart using chart.js

i am able to draw a line chart but want to display user defined values on 'Y' Axes. ie. If i have some value i.e 2 on Y Axes then i want to add some data on Below and Above of that 2.

i have some image which i want to create.

[image]

in above picture , i have mean at some value so i want to add +1s ,+2s and +3s above and below of that Mean value.

Help me on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `scaleLabel` option

```
  ...
  scaleLabel: function(valueObj) {
    if (valueObj.value === '0')
        return 'Mean'
    else if (Number(valueObj.value) > 0)
      return '+' + valueObj.value + 's';
    else
      return valueObj.value + 's';
  }
});
```

Note that unless your data range is static, you'll also need to override the scale.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Lbk9ughy/